# Undefined mixin 'map-get'

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4

I am working on Bootstrap4 with SASS.
now my question is when i define map it get error ("Undefined mixin 'map-get'")

I define this "`@include map-get($map-footer,footer-background);`" in my `footer.scss` file and i add mixins in another file.

I create  `_include-maps.scss` file for below scss.

```
$map-footer: ( 
  footer-background:( 
    context: (
      css-path: '.footer nav ul li a'
    ),
    properties: (
      background-color: #000, 
      color: #ffffff,
      font-size: 1.875rem
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Depends on where you define this mixin and where call it. Please, add some details to your question.

Comment: please check question again. Thank you very much

Comment: `map-get` is not a mixin, it is build in scss function. Functions are called without `@include` . This function returns value by key from map. http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method It should be mentioned that `map-get($map-footer, footer-background);` returns a map with `context` and `properties` keys.

Comment: Thank you @3rdthemagical :) .. Sorry for late rpl